# Unable to destroy eip association ressource: ErrorCode: IncorrectEipStatus

Tags: terraform, alibaba-cloud

I have provisioned an infrastructure with ECI group and an elastic ip address to communication with public internet.
I tried to destroy the infrastruture but I couldn't and I get and error with Error code ErrorCode: IncorrectEipStatus.
Please find below the details.

Thanks !

Terraform 0.14.4

Affected Resource(s):

- alicloud_eip_association
- alicloud_eip
- alicloud_eci_container_group

eip.tf code:

```
resource "alicloud_eip" "eip_address" {
bandwidth = "10"
internet_charge_type = "PayByBandwidth"
}

resource "alicloud_eip_association" "eip_asso" {
count = var.eci_count
allocation_id = alicloud_eip.eip_address.id
instance_id = alicloud_eci_container_group.eci_grp[count.index].id
}
```

eci.tf code:

```
resource "alicloud_eci_container_group" "eci_grp" {
count = var.eci_count
container_group_name = "tf-eci-group"
cpu = 0.5
memory = 1.0
restart_policy = "Never"
security_group_id = alicloud_security_group.sg-terraform.id
vswitch_id = alicloud_vswitch.VSwitch_terraform.id
tags = {
Terraform = "true"
}
containers {
image = //Docker image url
name = "Container1"
cpu = 0.25
memory = 0.5
image_pull_policy = "Always"
}

containers {
image = //Docker image url
name = "Container2"
cpu = 0.25
memory = 0.5
image_pull_policy = "Always"
}
}
```

Debug Output

```
Error: 1mError: [ERROR] terraform-provider-alicloud/alicloud/resource_alicloud_eip_association.go:180: Resource eip-gtthnc68ttfogpisicx:eci-gwookdcg65rs34svgibaar UnassociateEipAddress Failed!!! [SDK alibaba-cloud-sdk-go ERROR]: SDK.ServerError
ErrorCode: IncorrectEipStatus
Recommend: https://error-center.aliyun.com/status/search?Keyword=IncorrectEipStatus&source=PopGw
Message: Current elastic IP status does not support this operation.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Expected Behavior:

- To destroy the eip address and the association with ECI

Actual Behavior:

- Crashes with the message error mentioned herebefore

Steps to Reproduce:

- terraform destroy

Comment: I have the same error. Let's see what I find out.

Answer (score 0):

Run a `terraform refresh` prior to the `terraform destroy`, so that local state is updated with resources that have been automatically created during `terraform apply`.